# Как правильно присвоить значение инпутов для элементов?

Tags: javascript

Сорян за такие вопросы, разобраться пытался, честно. Как менять размер спанов независимо друг от друга?

```js
    document.querySelector('.size').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      const size = e.target.value
      const span = document.querySelectorAll('span')
    
      for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
        span[i].style.fontSize = size + 'px'
      }
    })
```

```html
    <div class="size">
      <input type="range" id="size-picker--one" min="20" max="50">
      <input type="range" id="size-picker--two" min="15" max="50">
    </div>
    <span class='text1'>TEXT 1</span><span class='text2'>TEXT 2</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.size').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let range = e.target;
  const size = range.value
  let spanId = range.dataset.spanId;
  const span = document.querySelector(`span[data-id="${spanId}"]`);
  span.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
});
```

```html
<div class="size">
  <input type="range" id="size-picker--one" data-span-id=1 min="20" max="50">
  <input type="range" id="size-picker--two" data-span-id=2 min="15" max="50">
</div>

<span class='text1' data-id=1>TEXT 1</span>
<span class='text2' data-id=2>TEXT 2</span>
```

Comment: а есть ли варианты, без использования data-id?

Comment: Можно. Через классы или другую разметку

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, является ли плохой практикой присваивать значение конкретному элементу, условно таким образом 'const valueElem = document.querySelector('text1').value' + elem.style...

Comment: Желательно чтобы всё было на своих местах и названо было понятно для других, а также чтобы была возможность переиспользовать данные. Иногда можно. Но оч. осторожно. Хоть я и не рекомендовал бы